# Hide access to Magento

Tags: magento2.3, nginx

I have a Magento that I would only like to access from another web portal. If the user copies the Magento base url, I don't want the portal to appear. You should only be able to access Magento if the user comes from another web portal that I decide.
What options to implement do I have?
I have thought of concatenating an MD5 string to the URL and in the Magento nginx if the request comes with the string I allow access and if not give a forbidden is this option correct?
Is there an alternative already implemented in Magento to meet this need?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The [ngx_http_referer_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html) would be a perfect candidate for your use case.

Simply list allowed referring domains and block the rest:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    valid_referers none blocked server_names 
        example.org;

    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Note, that the `Referer:` header is not guaranteed to be present, so you would really want to add those special values `none` and `blocked` for `valid_referers` directive.